# Multilple tables with same columns workaround

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm creating an attachments logic in my system, but I don't know what solution would be a better practice

I made some diagrams:

**Multiple table with same fields:**
[image]

**Only one table, but it references to all the others:**
[image]

Comment: The first image looks like an m:n relationship, while in the second one it looks more like 1:n. Also, you cannot have a foreign key constraint in your second image.

Comment: Is `AttachmentType` an attribute of the attachment, or can it be different each instance it is attached to something? Can it be attached multiple times? (Either way, the 2nd model seems broken.)